# How to add a JMeter comment block or element?

Tags: comments, jmeter, block, element

I would like to add some comment block or element in my JMeter script.

This would be useful to understand the script later on.

[image]

Currently, I have added a BSF Listeren, but this gives errors during execution.

Any idea's?

Comment: Good Question! Never really thought about documenting a jmeter test plan. I imagine you should be able to add a beanshell or JSR223 preprocessor or sampler, and just add a comment to it without code. I wonder if that would cause a performance issue at runtime from trying to spin up samplers that don't do anything - I suppose you could also disable the comment sampler/preprocessor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error does not come from Comments but from the fact that you didn't select any "Language" in your BSF Listener.

I tried it you can add comments in Beanshell for example using this syntax

> /**
>       * test
>       */

Note there is also a "Comment" field in all elements.

Comment: It is not working in `JMeter 3.2+`, commented lines appear in request too.